# show picture on another activity use button and edittext

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-emulator, android-linearlayout

i have a problem about showing picture, try using onclick method and gettext still can't be showing picture after input text on edittext.

here my code

activity first code java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText et;
private Button tombol;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tombol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL", "http://epiece.hostingforfree.com/cam_1.jpg");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
        });
}
```

second activity java code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

EditText et;
ImageView iv;
public Button tombol;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

 loadGambar();
 }

private void loadGambar(){

     try {  

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tombol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            URL url = new URL (et.getText().toString());
    InputStream is =  (InputStream) url.getContent();
    Drawable gambar = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    iv.setImageDrawable(gambar);
    is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 tombol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     String string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
     Intent intent=new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();

 }
 });
 }
}
```

nothing have error on this code but image still can't be showing, help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) First thing you should care about is you should not use main thread to load images from internet rather you should use an asyncTask(doInBackground method) to get image from internet and then in onPostExecute you can set the image to your imageView.

2) Here your mistake is you edittext is blank means you are pasing URL from intent but you are not getting it in SecondActivity.You can set url value to editText in loadGamber() by using

et.setText(intent.getStringExtra("URL"));

I hope this helps you..!!

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help...

You have done two mistakes in that codes..

1) You have given button name for `activity_main` , `activity_main2` same name `button1` you need to give separate name for both buttons like following codes

`activity_main`

```
tombol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

 tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("URL", "http://epiece.hostingforfree.com/cam_1.jpg");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
     });
```

`activity_main2`

```
tombo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

2) And you need to get the intent from main activity like bellow lines not in onclick

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    final string value = i.getExtras().getString("URL");
```